# Generate HTML customized checkbox with CSS

Tags: html, css

After some intensive googling, I am trying to get a dental chart that is clickable, but in vain. I want to replicate the following dental chart as shown in the image below. A tooth is divided into 5 sections. I want each section to be clickable. Please someone help to achieve this with HTML and CSS. I am not a Front-end expert.

[image]

Comment: @Badsha03. Any. luck with this? I also have been researching this for sometime now. Seems a really hard nut to crack using web technology. Some folks have suggested SVG however. Still looks like a lot of work without some sort of a plugin/package.

Answer (score 0):

Hide the checkbox and set background for an implemented span inside the checkbox label. You can replace those base64 images with proper image url:

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
.checkboxImage {
  display: inline-block;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  background: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAC4AAAAuCAIAAADY27xgAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAABISURBVFhH7c4xEQAgDAAxhHSsf2d4wMALYMhdBOTc2U+oFJWiUlSKSlEpKkWlqBSVolJUikpRKSpFpagUlaJSVIpKUSnfVGYf9ce4fGjX1qwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=')

}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + .checkboxImage {
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAC4AAAAuCAIAAADY27xgAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAABOSURBVFhH7c6hAYAwEMDAh1E6T5dlQwyODFBxZ2JzrWfPGe6vB7BSrBQrxUqxUqwUK8VKsVKsFCvFSrFSrBQrxUqxUqwUK8VKsVKs/M28laQBe2Rw8i4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=')

}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox"><span class="checkboxImage"></span></label>
```

Comment: No. This is not the desired output. How can I convert the above image uploaded into html with css?

Comment: This is another question. You have to set `background-position` and `background-size` one by one for every checkbox to set the desired part of that image in the background boundries. @Badshah03

Comment: How to do that please?

Comment: Please post a new question with desired details about background positioning. You may need to combine answers to that question with my answer to complete the taks @Badshah03